# Premature flowering and leaf fall in capsicum

Tags: flowering, leaf, capsicum

These are some capsicum saplings I have which were directly sown in this pot. There's premature flower budding and leaf fall of the first true leaves happening. What is causing this?

Location: Delhi, India.
[image]